# How to make a call in background of android application

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an application for android in which I need to make a call with MMI code in the background of the application. But by default the call application of the android phone is activated and I have to press call button from there. so I want solution for this....

Answer (score 2):

You can try the given simple code this is directly initiating a call to the no provided in code 123456789 and no call button is clicked for this. And yes dont forget to add permission in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
      b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {         
                 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                 callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
                 startActivity(callIntent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
                 Throwable e = null;
                 Log.e("helloandroid dialing example", "Call failed", e);
            }

      }});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would have provided some code than it would be helpful other wise have you declared in your app manifest file about the permission to modify phone state.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: String callForwardString = "#21#";    
              Intent intentCallForward = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL); // ACTION_CALL                               
              Uri uri2 = Uri.fromParts("tel", callForwardString, "#"); 
              intentCallForward.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
              intentCallForward.setData(uri2);                                
              startActivity(intentCallForward); 
              finish();